# Dynamically getting default of a parameter type

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic

### Question

I am trying to dynamically get the default for a type that is specified in a ParameterInfo. _methods[methodName] returns a MethodInfo object.

Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't like the "paramType" bit inside the default(paramType). I'm stumped.

### Error

> The type or namespace name 'paramType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> C:\Applications\...\MessageReceiver.cs Line 113

### Example

```
object blankObject = null;
foreach (var paramInfo in _methods[methodName].Key.GetParameters())
{
    if (paramInfo.Name == paramName)
    {
        Type paramType = paramInfo.ParameterType;
        blankObject = (object)default(paramType);
    }
}
parameters[i] = blankObject;
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's quite simple to implement:

```
public object GetDefault(Type type)
{
    return type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. It's great to have a celebrity answer my question. :) Repped.

Comment: Don't get too starstruck.  He answers _everyone's_ questions! :)

Comment: @Jon still valid 13 years later or there's something better nowadays?

Comment: @MatteoSp: I'd use an expression-bodied member now, but I don't know of a better way of achieving the goal :)

Answer (score 1):

I think default only works with the an actual type. It's a complier shortcut not an actual method. It works well with generics. for example:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T obj)
{
   T myvar = default(T);
}
```

Check out this question I posted a while back:

[Default Value for Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354136/default-value-for-generics)

Comment: Right... I've used it with generics a lot, but now I need to get it from a ParameterInfo. Surely there is a way to do this through reflection or something.