# C# to VB.NET: the **default** keyword?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default value for generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354136/default-value-for-generics)

OK, so while translating some code from C# to VB.NET, I came across the **default** keyword, and I'm simply replacing it with **nothing**.

Is this the proper way to do it, or is there a better "translation" for that keyword?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/354136/48082 , especially the 1st question asked there. The answers are good and provide background.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yup, that's absolutely fine. While `Nothing` is *usually* meant to mean the equivalent of C#'s `null`, it can be used with value types to, to mean "the default value of that type".

Comment: I just came across this writing a generic extension method, and it feels *so wrong*

Answer (score 0):

"default" is used in the context of generics, especially when you do not know the type but still want to have an instance of the default value of the generic type. I am not very good at Visual Basic, but I can imagine there is an equivalent to do the same(?).

For an example of the usage of the default keyword in C#, see *[default Keyword in Generic Code (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx)* (MSDN):

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be used with generics. You can just use (say) `default(string)` if you want. I would avoid using "instance" here - for example, `default(string)` is a null reference, rather than a reference to an instance of string.