# VB Nullables and Nothings

Tags: vb.net, default-value

I researched `C#`'s `default` keyword equivalence in VB.NET and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922803/c-sharp-to-vb-net-the-default-keyword).

Then I got curious.  Some background - I'm working with parsing an excel spreadsheet, where many columns can be null, and there is certainly a difference for me between an integer column being `0` and being `null`.

I wrote a little parse method:

```
Function Test(ByVal i As String) As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Dim j As Integer

    If Integer.TryParse(i, j) Then
        Return j
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

this seems to work correctly.  But here, I can return an `Integer` if i want:

```
Function Test(ByVal i As String) As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Return 2 'or Return Nothing
End Function
```

which I can in `C#` as well:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     int? j = Test("1");
 }

 public static int? Test(string i)
 {
     return 2; //or return null
 }
```

In the code above, if I change `j` to an `int`, I'll get a compile-time conversion error, which makes total sense.

Now my question - in VB, if i attempt a similar approach:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim j As Integer = Test("hello")
End Sub

Function Test(ByVal i As String) As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Dim j As Integer
    Return If(Integer.TryParse(i, j), j, Nothing)
End Function
```

or, in my test case where `i` is not an `Integer` it can be rewritten as:

```
Function Test(ByVal i As String) As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Return DirectCast(Nothing, Integer)
End Function
```

because of the way `Nothing` works in VB.NET, this code compiles and runs without error -- **j is set to Integer's default 0**.

This feels so dirty to me.  In this scenario you can somewhat alter the method's intentions without any warnings or errors.  I'm just curious I suppose, is this an unintentional by-product of the way `Nothing` works in VB, or is this the intended purpose?

Comment: Yes, Int's default to `0` in vb...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your VB.Net code compiles because you're using late binding, which allows changing the type of a variable at runtime.

If you compile your code with `OPTION STRICT ON`, you'll get a compiler error like:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Integer?' to 'Integer'.

Comment: thanks.  Simple explanation, but it makes sense.  More reasons why I really don't enjoy VB.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign `NULL` to a value type in VB.Net in which it instantiates that type with its default value. In your case you are not creating a `NULL` Integer, but an integer that holds the default value of 0.

Another good note: turn `Option Strict On`

Comment: Your first sentence contradicts your second one. Sure you can assign `Nothing` to a variable of a value type to get the default value of that type. You even say this in your second sentence.