# Is default(TSource) a real method?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

In [MSDN help page on **Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/bb340482(d=hv.2,v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) there is a method result explained as:

> default(TSource) if source is empty; otherwise, the first element in
>   source.

Remarks section contains note:

> The default value for reference and nullable types is null.

I was always doing check for `null` (VB.NET: `Nothing`) value but is there some `default(TSource)` which can be used instead of `null/Nothing` literal? (For example `default(int)`.)

I cannot find `default(TSource)` method, but it is mentioned on help page. Or isn't it a method?

**EDIT:** `default(TSource)` is visible on MSDN page for both C# and VB and I'm interested in answer covering both languages.

Comment: [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25tdedf5.aspx) - not a function or method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was always doing check for null (VB.NET: Nothing)

This not quite correct. `Nothing` is not the same as `null`; `Nothing` means `null` when assigned or compared to a nullable type (reference type or `Nullable<T>`) with `=` or when compared using `Is Nothing` and means the default value for a non-nullable value type it is assigned to or compared with `=`.

Hence the VB:

```
Dim b as Boolean = 0 = Nothing ' b is True
```

is **not** the same as the C#:

```
bool b = 0 == null; // b is false
```

but rather of:

```
bool b = 0 == default(int); // b is true
```

So the VB.NET equivalent of `default(T)` is indeed `Nothing` when not compared using `Is`.

In VB.NET you are not allowed to do `val Is Nothing` with `val` is not nullable, while in C# you can do `val == null` but it causes a warning (and always results in `false`).

In VB.NET you are allowed to do `val Is Nothing` with a generic type that *could be* nullable, and likewise with C# and `val == null`, in which case the check is that `val` is a nullable type *and* that it is set to null (and a waste-free one at that, generally in the case of a non-nullable type the jitter optimises away anything that would happen if `val == null`/`val Is Nothing` since it knows that can never happen).

The following VB.NET and C# methods are equivalent:

```
public static bool Demonstrate<T>(T x)
{
  T y = default(T);
  bool isNull = x == null;
  bool isDefault = x.Equals(default(T));
  int zero = default(int)
  return zero == default(int);
}

Public Shared Function Demonstrate(Of T)(x As T) As Boolean
  Dim y As T = Nothing
  Dim isNull As Boolean = x Is Nothing
  Dim isDefault As Boolean = x.Equals(Nothing)
  Dim zero As Integer = Nothing
  Return zero = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Perfect coverage of the `default()` problematics, thank you. Moving the answer mark here.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `default` operator, which is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx). It returns `null` for reference types, and a type-dependent default value for value types.

Answer (score 3):

[default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) is the keyword used to get the default value of `Type`. `TSource` is the generic type parameter. It is just the place holder for type token.

When the method is invoked with `IEnumerable<int>`, `TSource` will be `int`, `TSource` will be `String` when invoked with  `IEnumerable<String>` and so on. Given that  `default(TSource)` becomes `default(int)` in this case (invoked with `int`).

There is nothing like `default(TSource)` unless there exist a type `TSource` or a generic parameter exist with name `TSource`.

Comment: OK. To add VB.NET equivalent, I'm appending [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354136/default-value-for-generics).