# Hide parameterless constructor on struct

Tags: c#, .net, struct

Is it possible to hide the parameterless constructor from a user in C#?

I want to force them to always use the constructor with parameters

e.g. this Position struct

```
public struct Position
{
    private readonly int _xposn;
    private readonly int _yposn;
    
    public int Xposn
    {
        get { return _xposn; }
    }

    public int Yposn
    {
        get { return _yposn; }
    }

    public Position(int xposn, int yposn)
    {
        _xposn = xposn;
        _yposn = yposn;
    }        
}
```

I only want users to be able to new up a Position by specifying the x and y coordinates.

However, the parameterless constructor is ALWAYS available.

I cannot make it private. Or even define it as public.

I have read this:
[Why can't I define a default constructor for a struct in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333829/why-cant-i-define-a-default-constructor-for-a-struct-in-net)

but it doesn't really help.

If this is not possible - what is the best way to detect if the Position I am being passed has values?

Explicitly checking each property field? Is there a slicker way?

Comment: Re: "best way to detect if a struct has values" -- I updated my answer with the `Empty` and `IsEmpty` pattern that is found on some .NET structs. (I know this is a really old question!)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, you can't do this. As you said, [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333829) has been asked before - and I thought the answer was fairly clear that you couldn't do it.

You *can* [create a private parameterless constructor for a struct](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/12/10/value-types-and-parameterless-constructors), but not in C#. However, even if you do that it doesn't really help - because you can easily work around it:

```
MyStruct[] tmp = new MyStruct[1];
MyStruct gotcha = tmp[0];
```

That will be the default value of MyStruct - the "all zeroes" value - without ever calling a constructor.

You could easily add a Validate method to your struct and call that each time you received one as a parameter, admittedly.

Comment: I see this as a usability issue more than anything else.  The default constructor might make a _valid_ object, but for many structs it won't be what the user will want or expect.  Nonetheless some people will use that default constructor just because it's the first option their IDE gives them.  And then they'll have confusing bugs caused by zeroed-out structs that should have been filled with data, or they'll waste time trying to figure out why they can't set properties on an immutable struct.  From an API-design perspective I wish it were possible to hide the default constructor.

Comment: +1 @MB. A private default constructor would help, even if a determined "fool" can work around it.  As a C++ salt, I think of `private` as a hint to not shoot yourself in the foot, there is always a work-around using pointers.   And array semantics can be taken care of by just not allowing arrays of such structs to be created.

Comment: Hey Jon just one thing about parameterized constructors of struct. If you can validate it as I've read it somewhere. A parameterized constructor for a struct still calls default parameterless constructor (which his predefined for a struct in FCL) as first thing in its execution. I believe there is a compiler trick involved to achieve this behavior.

Comment: @RBT: There are changes in C# 6 around this in terms of whether you need to do so explicitly or not for automatically-implemented properties to work, but beyond that I don't think it's easily observable, unless you add a custom parameterless constructor via IL... my experience is that that isn't *always* called, but I suspect it's called from parameterized constructors... I'd have to check, but it's not something I've ever actually seen in real code anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Nope can't hide it. Structs cannot redefine zero arg constructor, so therefore its visibility can't be redefined.

Comment: Well, .NET allows you to provide a custom parameterless constructor - but you can't do it *directly* in C# and it doesn't help much anyway, as you can easily work around it.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to hide the parameterless constructor from a user in
> C#?

No, you cannot make a struct with a private parameter-less constructor or even declare a parameter-less constructor. You would have to change it to a class. Structs are not allow to declare a parameterless constructor.

> What is the best way to detect if the Position I am being passed has
> values?

One option to detect if a struct has values is to create an `Empty` instance and an `IsEmpty` method/property, similar to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68914164/29762). Here are some examples:

```
// System.Guid
public struct Guid : IFormattable, IComparable, IComparable<Guid>, IEquatable<Guid>
{
    public static readonly Guid Empty;
    //...
}

// System.Drawing.Point
public struct Point
{
    public static readonly Point Empty;
    public bool IsEmpty { get; }
    //...
}

// From your question above:
public struct Position
{
    public static readonly Position Empty = new Position();

    public bool IsEmpty => _xposn == 0 && _yposn == 0;

    private readonly int _xposn;
    private readonly int _yposn;

    public int Xposn
    {
        get { return _xposn; }
    }

    public int Yposn
    {
        get { return _yposn; }
    }

    public Position(int xposn, int yposn)
    {
        _xposn = xposn;
        _yposn = yposn;
    }
}
```

### Background

From the [Structs Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471(VS.71).aspx) on MSDN:

Structs can declare constructors, but they must take parameters. It is an error to declare a default (parameterless) constructor for a struct. Struct members cannot have initializers. A default constructor is always provided to initialize the struct members to their default values.

From the [C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664471(VS.71).aspx) on MSDN:

**11.3 Class and struct differences**

Structs differ from classes in several important ways:

- Structs are value types (Section
  11.3.1).
- All struct types implicitly inherit
  from the class System.ValueType
  (Section 11.3.2).  Assignment to a
  variable of a struct type creates a
  copy of the value being assigned
  (Section 11.3.3).
- The default value of a struct is the
  value produced by setting all value
  type fields to their default value
  and all reference type fields to null
  (Section 11.3.4).  Boxing and
  unboxing operations are used to
  convert between a struct type and
  object (Section 11.3.5).
- The meaning of this is different for
  structs (Section 11.3.6).
- Instance field declarations for a
  struct are not permitted to include
  variable initializers (Section
  11.3.7).
- **A struct is not permitted to declare
  a parameterless instance constructor
  (Section 11.3.8).**
- A struct is not permitted to declare
  a destructor (Section 11.3.9).

Answer (score 3):

Well a struct is literally a declaration of how the memory will sit.

Even when you use an object, the objects pointer IS declared, regardless of whether it's null.

The reason that you can't hide the constructor is because the struct demands that the CLR can create it as internally it must do this.

You could convert this struct into an object to achieve this task.  Or use static analysis to ensure it's intialized before you use it?

```
struct point
{
   int xpos;
   int ypos;
}
```

Have a google for immutable objects, this appears to be what your after.  I believe that they are looking to add this feature (but not in C# 4) to the language itself, because it is a common requirement.  Is there a specific need for a struct here?

Comment: what do you mean by this?
use static analysis to ensure it's intialized 

you mean check each field has a value?

Comment: You can run a static analysis tool with a rule to ensure that any time someone uses the type in their code that the two values are intialized.  or you could do some fancy footwork by declaring it as an object to do the check, and then change to a struct in the release build.