# C# struct, how to assign a null value?

Tags: c#, struct, nullable

I have a list:

```
List<int, SomeStruct>
```

For some reason, it is not allowing me to assign null values to it. What do I do if I want to have no struct associated?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx):

```
List<int, SomeStruct?>
```

You can't assign `null` to an element of the list because structs are value types, while `null` means an empty pointer, and so can only be assigned to reference type variables.

Also note that `List` as you're using it doesn't exist in .NET! Perhaps you want [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)?

Comment: When I do this, any references the the structures member now gives me the error: System.Nullable<> does not contain a definition for 'Member'

Comment: @whydna: Read up on nullable types. Essentially `SomeStruct?` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<SomeStruct>`. You can't access members directly, but that's the price you pay for using `null` semantics with a value type.

Answer (score 15):

In C# a struct is a 'value type', which can't be null.

If you really, really need to be able to null this, then make it into a 'nullable' type by adding a trailing question mark.

You should probably look into the details of this more first, though - it's quite likely you don't really want a 'struct' at all, but would be better with a 'class'.

Comment: Agreed. Problem is I don't own the Struct, I am simply using it :(

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have defined a custom generic collection, `List<T, U>` doesn't exist in the [`System.Collections.Generic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) namespace. Did you rather mean `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

You can use Nullable types: [`Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx).

As for any ValueType, you need to specify explicitly that you will allow null values for your type. You can do so by concatenating the '`?`' character with your type name, or by marking it as Nullable, where T is the name of your structure.

Comment: I couldn't resist to answering when I saw there was going to be three 'Will' answering one question! =P

Comment: Where there are three Wills there are three Ways?

Answer (score 2):

All of the existing answers here are correct: in C# struct is a `value type` and cannot be `null`.

However some struct implementations (but definitely not all) follow a convention where the default/empty value is stored in a `Empty` static field. Sometimes there is also an `IsEmpty` property:

```
// System.Guid
public struct Guid : IFormattable, IComparable, IComparable<Guid>, IEquatable<Guid>
{
    public static readonly Guid Empty;
    ...
}

// System.Drawing.Point
public struct Point
{
    public static readonly Point Empty;
    public bool IsEmpty { get; }
    ...
}
```

If the struct has an `Empty` field or `IsEmpty` property, then you can use it to test if the struct variable is `Empty` instead of `null`. Otherwise use a nullable wrapper as the other answers state.

If you are the programmer of the struct, strongly consider adding an `Empty` field and `IsEmpty` property if appropriate.