# How can I check if a struct is not null in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to search a List for an struct object and see if the returned object is not null

```
MyMap e_res_i = myMaps.Find(o => o.idx.ToString() == "1");
if(e_res_i != null)
{

}
```

And I get the error
`Operator != cannot be applied to operands of type MyMap and <null>`

How can I check if the returned value is null without converting the struct to a class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148810/c-sharp-struct-how-to-assign-a-null-value

Comment: Also, as a random guess, would maintaining a `Dictionary<String, MyMap>` keyed on `o.idx.ToString()` suit you better?

Comment: What exactly is `MyMap`? and `myMaps`? And the `o` in `myMaps`? And if `idx` is `Int32` then why are you calling `ToString()` instead of just doing `.Find( o => o.idx == 1 )` ?

Comment: First thing that you should have troubleshooted: what is the value of `e_res_i` when `myMaps` does not contain the item you're trying to find? It makes no sense that you're already trying to write the `if` logic to catch "not found" values when you clearly haven't even looked at what the "not found" value _is_ to begin with.

Comment: It's quite rude to assume you don't know that structs can't be null... so I'm confused why you are asking how to compare struct to null. Could you please [edit] the question to clarify that a) you know structs can't be null and b) what exactly you want to achieve and what data types you start from?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Structs can be null when they're enclosed in a `Nullable<T>` (or boxed, ofc) and that fact can be disguised when the code uses a `using MyType = Nullable<MyStruct>` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Structs are value types and can’t be `null`; `Find` will return the default value instead. As noted in the [documentation for `Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=net-8.0#remarks),

> When searching a list containing value types, make sure the default value for the type does not satisfy the search predicate. Otherwise, there is no way to distinguish between a default value indicating that no match was found and a list element that happens to have the default value for the type. If the default value satisfies the search predicate, use the [`FindIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=net-8.0) method instead.

```
int e_res_i_index = myMaps.FindIndex(o => o.idx.ToString() == "1");
if (e_res_i_index != -1)
{
    MyMap e_res_i = myMaps[e_res_i_index];
    // ...
}
```

And, like it hints at, if you know that the default value for your type doesn’t match the predicate (and the example does look that way), you *can* correctly compare to it:

```
MyMap e_res_i = myMaps.Find(o => o.idx.ToString() == "1");
if (e_res_i != default(MyMap))
{
    // ...
}
```

I wouldn’t recommend that, though – it’s fragile.

Another option is to use [nullables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) in some way:

```
MyMap? e_res_i =
    myMaps
    .Where(o => o.idx.ToString() == "1");
    .Select<MyMap, MyMap?>(o => o)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (e_res_i is not null)
{
    // ...
}
```

And you can wrap any of these approaches in a(n extension) method if you want, too.