# How to prevent use of default constructor?

Tags: c#

We are creating a simple struct with a constructor accepting one argument.

```
public struct test
{
    public int val;

    public test (int a)
    {
        val = a;
    }
}
```

Yet I notice that the struct can be initialized using the default constructor.  Can this be prevented?

```
test t1 = new test();   //why does this work?
```

Comment: Not a duplicate any more, now that this is about structs.

Comment: What you want to achieve is not possible in C#  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535328/hide-parameterless-constructor-on-struct

Comment: There is difference between classes and structs, and this behaviour is one of them. As I do not see any benefits in structs in C#, all my structs are now value objects. To me struct seems to be a feature for familiarizing C/C++ programmers with C#, but has no inherent benefit in this language.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot prevent the usage of the default constructor in C# for value types. A default constructor is required by the C# specification and it is added automatically by the compiler (in fact you cannot define it explicitly). The runtime provides that any value type can be created without calling a constructor to an "all-zero" instance. I'm guessing the C# language designers decided to make that feature of the CLR more explicit by requiring a default parameterless constructor for structs.

Comment: Since I was going to include it in my answer, here is the C# spec for a struct: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taef578.aspx

Comment: Why is it possible for class?

Comment: @NachiketKamat It is possible for classes because the C# language designers made it possible. More importantly, there is no way to initialize a class without calling a constructor in the CLR but there is for structs.