# Why struct can not have parameterless constructor

Tags: c#

Why struct can not have parameterless constructor?
What's the problem in doing this for CLR or why it's not allowed ?
Please explain it as I don't understand it.

Comment: Duplicate: [Why can’t I define a default constructor for a struct in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333829/why-cant-i-define-a-default-constructor-for-a-struct-in-net)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I cannot have an explicit parameterless constructor, only the implicit one, that initializes all members to their default.

> Although the CLR allows it, C# does
>   not allow structs to have a default
>   parameterless constructor. The reason
>   is that, for a value type, compilers
>   by default neither generate a default
>   constructor, nor do they generate a
>   call to the default constructor. So,
>   even if you happened to define a
>   default constructor, it will not be
>   called and that will only confuse you.
>   To avoid such problems, the C#
>   compiler disallows definition of a
>   default constructor by the user. And
>   because it doesn't generate a default
>   constructor, you can't initialize
>   fields when defining them, ...

Answer (score 2):

Quite a reasonable explanation can be found at:
http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ:_Why_must_struct_constructors_have_at_least_one_argument

Quoting:
*"The .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR) does not guarantee that parameterless constructors will be called. If structs were permitted to have default, parameterless constructors, the implication would be that default constructors would always be called. Yet, the CLR makes no such guarantee."*

Comment: The link no longer works.