# How CLR can bypass throwing error when assigning a null value to the struct?

Tags: c#, struct, nullable

I am trying to understand one thing in this code:

```
Nullable<Int32> x = 5;
Nullable<Int32> y = null;
Console.WriteLine("x: HasValue={0}, Value={1}",  x.HasValue, x.Value);
Console.WriteLine("y: HasValue={0}, Value={1}",  y.HasValue, y.GetValueOrDefault());
```

And Output is:

```
x: HasValue=True, Value=5
y: HasValue=False, Value=0
```

And the thing that I don't understand when you pass `null` to `y`, I believe it calls `public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T value)` but the definition of this method initializes a new struct passing `value` which is assigned `null` however constructor method doesn't check whether it is null or not so it can assign `default(T)` to `value`.

**How come we can even assign null to struct here and it works fine?**

Can you guys what I am missing out here? I don't understand how it just bypassed `null` and returned default value.

**Nullable code inner definition:**

http://codepaste.net/gtce6d

Comment: any reason why you aren't using the built in `Nullable<T>` struct?

Comment: I am just learning the internal structure of nullable types.

Comment: As a sidenote: Your `Equals` implementation is broken. If both sides are your custom nullable, and both are custom-null, it will return false, but should return true. | It also shouldn't compile, because you can't have initializers on instance fields for structs.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: It is taken from CLR with C# 3.0 though.

Comment: Oh in that case, it works, since there is sufficent compiler and runtime magic in the background. And the code you give isn't any real code, it's just an approximation.

Comment: #CodeInChaos: You mean it doesn't work? Well I didn't work in real environment though.

Comment: CodeInChaos is wrong about the code not working -- it does work. However, he is right that it works because the compiler and CLR have special magic to handle `Nullable<>` types. Ultimately, that's probably the answer to your question.

Comment: Both the compiler and the jitter have built-in knowledge of Nullable<> and give it special treatment.  You cannot get them to treat your own MyNullable<> type the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> believe it calls public static implicit operator Nullable(T value)

No it doesn't, because `T` is `Int32` in this case, and `null` is not an `Int32`. It just leaves the `y` variable default, which means for a struct that all bytes are `0`. This results in a struct that has a `HasValue` that returns `false`.

You can't really pass `null` to a struct, but the C# compiler is converting this for you to a default initalization.

Comment: Then what makes this struct `Nullable` and `Int32` not? How come you can assign `null` which doesn't throw an error yet `Int32` does? It is because it has `implicit` overloading?

Comment: What makes it nullable is that you defined is at nullable<x>. Nullable struct has some compiler magic behind to make it easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

The default is assigned in the constructor called by `new Nullable<T>(value);` (Line 40)

Comment: But how come we can pass a null to the struct?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that assigning `null` to a nullable calls the default constructor. That is the only possible way for `hasValue` to remain `false`.

Comment: Can't they have some `if` statements to check whether they should change the HasValue property?

Comment: @YoryeNathan maybe they could, but there aren't any. actually, although it doesn't say `readonly` on the fields, the struct is designed to be immutable. hasValue and value are both only ever set in constructors; so yeah, while it's not shown in the code, the default constructor is the only way to get a value of `null`.

Comment: But `struct` cannot have parameterless constructor. How come it calls it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575901/why-struct-can-not-have-parameterless-constructor

Comment: @Braveyard If I recall, `struct`s have an *implicit* default constructor that you cannot modify. It always sets everything to their default values. While the code snippet shows the fields being initialized explicitly, that would actually give you a compile error. I'm guessing that the code viewing tool is just showing the compiler's default initializers.

Answer (score 1):

A `Nullable<T>` is simply a structure which has a boolean field indicating whether it has a value, and a field which (if the first field is true) indicates what that value is.  It isn't really possible to set any structure to `null`, and a `Nullable<T>` is no exception.  Instead, the compiler translates a request to set a `Nullable<T>` to `null` as a request to set the "has value" field (reflected in property `HasValue`) to false and set the "actual value" field (reflected in property `Value`) to the default for its type.

Personally, I think pretending that a `Nullable<T>` where `HasValue` is false is `null` is more confusing than helpful, but I am not Microsoft.  I would think it would have been more helpful for each `Nullable<T>` type to have a static property `Nullable<T>.Null` (which would be equivalent to `default(Nullable<T>)`, but the behavior of `Nullable<T>` is sufficiently well-established I doubt it will ever change.