# Why I cannot have instance field initializers in structs in C#?

Tags: c#, struct

I've got the error message said "cannot have instance property or field initializers in structs" and wonder if there is any technical reason for this? Why doesn't a compiler behave like an initialization happens in a constructor?

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: @Servy that doesn't answer the *why* IMHO.

Comment: @mybirthname Why? The question is valid without code.

Comment: A struct is not allowed to have a default constructor.  Which is what is needed to get fields initialized.  Use a class instead.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575901/why-struct-can-not-have-parameterless-constructor