# C# struct non-static struct member cannot have initializer

Tags: c#, struct

What is the cause of the error on the screen?

```
public struct  YetkiYapisiListesi
{
    public bool STOKGUNCELLE =false ;
    public bool STOKSIL=false;
    public bool STOKLISTELE=false;
}
```

> Non-static struct member cannot have initializer

Answer (score 1):

C# does not allow `struct`s to have initializers, the reason why has been debated before, see here: ( [Why can't I initialize my fields in my structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609831/why-cant-i-initialize-my-fields-in-my-structs) )

Simply remove the `= false` part from your field declarations.

Note that `Boolean` fields are `false` by default, making your assignment completely unnecessary.

If you absolutely need fields to have initialized to non-default values then you can still define an additional constructor that sets those values, however it cannot be the default (parameterless) constructor. One alternative option then, is to use a static factory method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize field on Struct.

You will get the same result even if you ommit initializing  :

```
public bool STOKGUNCELLE;
public bool STOKSIL;
public bool STOKLISTELE;
public bool STOKHAREKET;
```

Because **bool default value are false** .