# How to avoid error 'cannot-have-instance-field-initializers-in-structs-problem' in web service

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, struct

```
public struct sFr
{
    public sFe[] errorDetails;

    public sFr(sFe[] _errorDetails)
    {
        // ?? whats code to initialise the array without getting error
        // as this throws null ref when used later from client calling this webservice

        errorDetails = _errorDetails;

        // do we need to create the array of elements which we populate ?
    }
}
```

Comment: When posting code, please format it appropriately (using the {} button), and check the formatting in the preview area.

Comment: There are a few problems with the code you posted: The second pair of brackets is in the wrong place and you have two versions of the casing of `sFe`. Normally initialization would just be `errorDetails = _errorDetails;`

Comment: and of course, no field-initializer... I'm not sure this code really shows the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of ["cannot have instance field initializers in structs" problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406178/cannot-have-instance-field-initializers-in-structs-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple fix; don't make it a struct.

Sorry, but a struct there is just plain wrong...

As are public fields, and *usually* arrays (prefer lists)

And overly abbreviated names (use things like `[XmlRoot("sFr"), XmlType("sFr")]` if you need to control the serialization, but make the type-name meaningful).

Re the error; the syntax should just be `this.fieldName = value;`

I'd have something like:

```
public sealed class ErrorResult
{
    private readonly List<SomeErrorType> errors = new List<SomeErrorType>();
    public List<SomeErrorType> Errors { get { return errors; } }
    public ErrorResult() {} // make explicit so never lost
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @Marc, however I have to somehow format the array for errordetails inside the structure, have real problems getting it to work. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @Lambo - that is very vague; what is your desired input/output... "somehow format the array" isn't clear

Comment: Sorry for being so vague, we have web service which returns structs with the array in it - we wish to emulate this and the code aboce seeks to do that - but fails as we cannot form the array correctly.

Comment: @Lambo a web service returns xml (typically; could also be a few other formats), not structs. If the issue is getting the correct xml layout, then please post an example of the correct xml layout.  It is usually a matter of simply adding the write attributes to the members. And it really, honestly, truly doesn't have to be a struct. That is causing unnecessary problems here...

Comment: Right thanks @Marc once again you have helped steer me in the right direction. Ill keep chipping away thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

```
sFr instance = new sFr(array_of_details);
```

(which is what you're trying to do), I think the correct way would be:

```
sFr instance = new sFr();
instance.errorDetails = array_of_details;
```

If you want to do the first, I think you should create a `class` instead of a `struct`.

Come to think of it: When creating a web service passing a struct between server and client, I think a parameterless constructor is expected, because the usual way is that an instance is created an then the fields are deserialized.