# Struct Implicit Default Constructor vs. Parameterless Constructor

Tags: c#, .net

OK, we hear that `struct`cannot have a default parameterless constructor which is fine (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333829/why-cant-i-define-a-default-constructor-for-a-struct-in-net). But documentation says "Each value type has an implicit default constructor that initializes the default value of that type." from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx

What's the difference between implicit default constructor and parameterless default constructor right now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implicit default constructor *is* the parameterless constructor which is automatically created by the compiler.  The reason you can't create a parameterless constructor is because the default one already exists.  I don't know why they chose to do it this way, and why you're not allowed to override it.

Comment: It is the same with class but you can override it :)

Comment: As it admits it only really half answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the answer you point to, using IL, you can define a parameterless constructor for a `struct`, but there are scenarios where it is not called.

IMHO the "implicit" constructor is just a logical one; implied by the memory being zeroed out when it is allocated.

Comment: You can see that answer in my question. I linked it already actually :)