# Why structure in C# cannot have explicit default constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, struct

What is the internal reason that in C# structure cannot have an explicit default constructor?

Answer (score 1):

From [`Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx)

> Constructors for struct types resemble class constructors, but structs
>   cannot contain an explicit default constructor because one is provided
>   automatically by the compiler.

Chech this [Why can't I define a default constructor for a struct in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333829/why-cant-i-define-a-default-constructor-for-a-struct-in-net)

Comment: why it couldn't like in C++ - when explicit default constructor provided use it, when it is not provided generate and use provided by compiler?

Comment: @BorisPitel: The .NET assumes that a storage location of *any type* may be initialized to its default value by filling the memory it occupies with zeroes.  This will set locations of reference types or `Nullable<T>` to `null`, will set numeric primitives to zero, and will set all fields of structures to the default values of their respective types.  Such a design means that the system can initialize any type--no matter how complicated--simply by filling it with zero.  Note also that the usefulness of being able to automatically call more complicated constructors...

Comment: ...will in many cases hinge upon the ability to specify copy constructors and C++-style destructors; here again, .NET assumes that the only thing necessary to copy a struct is to copy the memory occupied thereby (which again merely requires knowing the size), and the only thing necessary to destroy a struct is to abandon or overwrite the space it occupies.  Such assumptions greatly simplify the Framework and languages.  While I will readily grant that proper struct constructors, copy constructors, and destructors are often useful, it's not clear that they're worth their substantial cost.