# Why class required default constructor but structure dont required?

Tags: c#, class, struct

Look into following code

```
public class ABC
{
    public ABC(int a)
    {
    }
}

public struct XYZ
{
    public XYZ(int a)
    {
    }
}

public class Test
{
    //This is invalid.
    ABC _abc = new ABC();

    //This is valid. Why?
    XYZ _xyz = new XYZ();
}
```

Why `struct` dont required default constructor where as `class` required same?

Comment: [Why can't I define a default constructor for a struct in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333829/why-cant-i-define-a-default-constructor-for-a-struct-in-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *always* a parameterless constructor in a `struct` - and you can't define your own one. It will always initialize all fields to their default values. This is effectively a requirement of the CLR, although the CLR itself doesn't refer to this as a constructor, and is described in section 11.3.8 of the C# spec. (Although C# doesn't allow you to declare your own parameterless constructor for structs, the CLR does - and it's *sometimes* called. See [my blog post on the topic](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/12/10/value-types-and-parameterless-constructors.aspx) for more information.)

The value created by calling the parameterless constructor on a `struct` is always the same as an "uninitialized" value in an array or an instance/static field.

Classes, however, have a different "default" value, as a field (or array element) of a reference type will be `null` by default. There is no guaranteed way of creating an *instance* of a class without specifying any values. If you specify *any* constructors yourself for a class, the C# compiler will not provide a default constructor, as described in section 10.11.4 of the C# spec.

Comment: The fact that there exists a parameterless constructor is I think less relevant than the fact that normal ways of creating a struct instance (e.g. declaring a field of a structure type) don't involve any code within the struct itself. As you've said on your blog, the Framework doesn't require structs to have do-nothing parameterless constructors, but the fact that struct instance creation doesn't involve struct code means there'd be little to gain by having a struct do anything else.

Comment: @supercat: I think all those aspects are at least somewhat relevant - in particular, the presence of a parameterless constructor (in C# terms) is very, very relevant to the question of "why is this code valid?" for `new XYZ()`

Comment: I see your point about what's "more" relevant to the direct question asked, but would nonetheless suggest that the original poster (and many other people) might find a link to your blog post to be helpful and informative.

Comment: @supercat: Sure, will add that now.

Answer (score 2):

Because the default constructor of a class (reference type) is only exposed if an explicit one is not implemented (that is, it doesn't exist). A struct (value type) doesn't even need to be `new`'d, so to speak. You can use a variable that represents a struct without it - i.e. it won't be `null`, anyway (that is, it needn't exist at all).

Answer (score 1):

When a storage location (variable, field, array slot, etc.) of a class type is first created, it holds `null`.  When a storage location of a structure type is first created, it holds an instance of the type in which every byte has been set to zero.  Unlike C++, .NET provides no means for a type to exercise any say over when storage locations of that type may be created, nor what should happen when they are.

If `Foo` is a class type and code creates an array `bar = new Foo[100]`, the array will be created with 100 slots that don't contain references to `Foo` (they're initially `null`).  Code that wants to make any array slot hold a reference to a `Foo` will have to somehow get its hands on one, and the only way any references to `Foo` will exist is if someone asks the class to create one (by calling its constructor).

By contrast, if `Moo` is a structure type, creating an array `boz = new Moo[100]`, the array will be created with 100 slots, *each one of which **is** a `Moo` instance*.  Whereas a `Foo` can hold a value (`null`) which doesn't refer to an instance of `Foo`, none of the array slots will be capable of holding anything other than `Moo` instances.  Since creating an array of `Moo` inherently creates instances of `Moo` without the type having any say in the matter, there's really no mechanism by which a struct type could assert control over instance creation.