# How to print n times n without loops, recursivity or goto in C#

Tags: c#, c++, constructor

I have this code in c++ to do this but I want to do the same in C# but it's not working and I can't figure it out why?

```
    class Numero
{
   public:
   static int num;
   Numero()
   {
       cout<<num++<<" ";
   }
};

int Numero::num=1;

int main()
{
   int n;
   cout<<"Type n: ";
   cin>>n;
   Numero obj[n];
   return 0;

}
```

this print "1 2 3 4 5 .... n" 
but in C#

```
class numero
    {
        public static int num {get; set;}
        public numero()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            num++;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            numero.num=1;
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'n'");
            int n = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Printing to: {0}", n);
            numero[] num_1 = new numero[n]; 
            Console.WriteLine("End");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I tried in diferent ways but the only I get is:

> ```
> Type 'n'
> 10
> Printing to: 10
> End
> ```

any idea in how to make it works? and why when creating the class numero it's not calling the numero constuctor??

Comment: In C#, unlike C++, an array of `T[]` does *not* automatically call the/a default constructor for each T item automatically - instead the fields will be initialized to `null` when T is a reference type. (So the C++ approach, which is mostly a hack relying on side-effects won't work in C# :-)

Comment: @user2864740: fascinating!  thank you.

Comment: You can hide iteration in LINQ obviously like `Enumerable.Range(1,n).Select(i => {Console.WriteLine(i);return i;})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ version works because you're allocating `n` many elements of `Numero` on the stack which causes the compiler to invoke `Numero`'s constructor `n` times. Ultimately your program is still using a loop, but it's hidden within the generated machine code rather than explicitly delcared in your code.

The psuedocode of the machine-code generated by the compiler resembles this:

```
 numbers = Allocate( n * sizeof( Number ) );
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++) numbers[i].ctor();
```

**This is not possible in pure C#** because classes exist on the heap and require explicit constructor calls (which you'd have to do in a loop), and while structs exist on the stack  ([sort-of](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx)) they do not have their default constructor called when they're allocated (see this QA for an explanation: [Why can't I define a default constructor for a struct in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333829/why-cant-i-define-a-default-constructor-for-a-struct-in-net) ).

Your question sounds like a bad brain-teaser question that tests one's familiarity with a language, but has zero practical use because the only way to implement a loop is with a jump instruction *somewhere* (be it a loop, recursive call, or explicit goto; there are no other ways to do this - the only way to hide it is by calling another method or compiler-feature that performs the prohibited instruction).

Note that you *could* pull this off with `Array.Initialize` which will call the default constructor of a value-type array's elements, but C# doesn't allow you to define such a default constructor (but the CLI does allow them to exist). This might be to allow for some Managed C++ / C++/CLR interop feature, however.