# C# Value type Initialization mystery

Tags: c#, .net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx

in the above mentioned article i read .
"**Each value type has an implicit default constructor that initializes the default value of that type**."

**But in this article Jon Skeet says**

[Why can't I define a default constructor for a struct in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333829/why-cant-i-define-a-default-constructor-for-a-struct-in-net/333840#333840)

"the basic rule in C# is **"the default value for any type can't rely on any initialization"**
means as mentioned in comments.
 The default value is always "what you'd get by wiping memory". You can't provide any explicit implementation which will always be called.

**Can anybody tell me who is correct ?**

what actually happens when a value type is declared its constructor is called or memory is wiped out.

Comment: I think both article conveys the same message, value type has an implicit default constructor, even the 'Struct'. So, you can't create another default constructor (without parameters) for struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both links don't contradict each other. It would help if you could explain why you think so.

You seem to think *"the default value for any type can't rely on any initialization"* means *"value types don't get initialized"*, which is not true. [They get initialized to 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).

What Jon means to say there (and does say) is *"Users can't provide a custom constructor for value types"*.

Comment: if you read the comment  **The default value is always "what you'd get by wiping memory".**.  Who wipes out the memory ?  is it like value types are assigned some junk value in memory when they are declared and then a wiping out process comes and assigns them their default value. what is the role of constructor in this?

Comment: The runtime, which is the CLR, does the wiping. When you allocate a piece of memory (to store a struct in), that memory can be filled with garbage because it was previously used to store something else. This has to be zeroed, and the runtime does so at `initobj`. A value type _has no constructor and can't have any_, at least until C# 6.

Comment: i am referring implicit default constructor as mentioned in MSDN article in my question. Which say "Each value type has an implicit default constructor that initializes the default value of that type."

Comment: Keyword being "implicit". It doesn't have one, but it pretends to, so you can `new` it (which will be compiled to `initobj`). There's a difference between the features a language offers (C#) and what the runtime (CLR) supports.

Answer (score 3):

> what actually happens when a value type is declared its constructor is
>   called or memory is wiped out.

Lets say you have the following:

```
public struct Foo
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public object B { get; set; }
}
```

and you allocate a `Foo`:

```
var f = new Foo();
```

The compiler emits a call to [`initobj`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.initobj%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
IL_0001:  ldloca.s    00 // f
IL_0003:  initobj     UserQuery.Foo
```

> Initializes each field of the value type at a specified address to a
>   null reference or a 0 of the appropriate primitive type

And goes on to describe *how* they get initialized:

> The initobj instruction initializes each field of the value type
>   specified by the pushed address (of type native int, &, or *) to a
>   **null reference or a 0** of the appropriate primitive type. After this
>   method is called, the instance is ready for a constructor method to be
>   called. If typeTok is a reference type, this instruction has the same
>   effect as ldnull followed by stind.ref. Unlike Newobj, initobj does
>   not call the constructor method. **Initobj is intended for initializing
>   value types, while newobj is used to allocate and initialize objects.**

All this actually convies the fact the value types *do* get initialized (as it seems that from your question you may question that statement).

Note that as of **C# 6.0**, you *can* declare a default parameterless constructor for a value type. If you do, it will be invoked if you explicitly instantiate your value type via the `new` operator.

[Mads Torgersen explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx):

> The expression ‘new Person()’ will execute the declared constructor
>   instead of the standard behavior of providing the default value. Note,
>   however, that ‘default(Person)’ will still produce the default value,
>   as will ‘new Person[…]’ for each of the array elements. In those cases
>   the constructor is not executed: It’s only when you explicitly use
>   ‘new’ on the struct type.

Who wipes it out is the same for all managed CLR types, the garbage collector. It will notice that it is no longer pointed to, and will collect the type and do its magic.

Comment: you mean to say constructor has no role in initializing value type?all work is done by Initobj  method. If so why it is written in MSDN  article i mentioned in my question . ** "Each value type has an implicit default constructor that initializes the default value of that type."**

Comment: @GauravMoolani *initobj* is the IL opcode that gets executed when you declare `new ValueType()`. Of course it has a role, that is why it is an *implicit constructor*, you don't declare it, but it will run *anyway*.

Comment: means by  calling the implicit constructor of a value type .net calls initobj   method of CLR and it wipes out all memory and  assigns default value to value type . thanks i got it.

Answer (score 0):

It's really no mystery at all.  All value types are initialized using an implicit default constructor that is responsible for assigning a default value to the type. In fact, here's a link that shows the default values for each value type.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx