# Does the new keyword calls the default constructor of the struct or does it call the default constructors of its members?

Tags: c#, struct, constructor

I have read that a struct in C# does not have a default constructor. But when I use the `new` keyword to create a struct, the members of the struct will be initialized, so how does this happen, does the `new` keyword calls the default constructors for the members of the struct?

Comment: Who told you that structs don't have a default constructor?  Whoever told you that was simply incorrect, as you yourself have just proven with a trivial test.

Comment: From the docs: Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors. Struct members are automatically initialized to their default values.

Comment: @Servy I have read it in this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBIt1smjpfM

Comment: @rony Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024229/c-sharp-value-type-initialization-mystery/28024366#28024366)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does the new keyword calls the default constructors for the members of the struct?

No - each member will be initialized to its default value: 0 (or its equivalent) for value types; null for reference types.  If the struct contains another struct, that struct will be constructed using default values as well.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Struct members are automatically initialized to their default values.