# Parameterless constructor in Structure

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32122660/592111) on using different Visual Basic versions in [Visual Studio 2015](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2015), I'm running through the new lanugage features in Visual Basic 14, as documented [here](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status) and [here](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/571884).

One of those is the ability to have parameterless constructors in structures, like this:

```
Structure MyStruct1
   Public f As Integer
   Sub New()
      f = 15
   End Sub
End Structure
```

When I try this in code in Visual Studio 2015, I'm still getting an red error squiggle under the `New()`:

> BC30629 Structures cannot declare a non-shared 'Sub New' with no parameters.

I haven't seen anywhere that states that this got pulled before release.

Am I mis-understanding what this new feature does?

Comment: I don't have an answer, however I can confirm that it doesn't work in VS 2015 (Community), independent on what framework is targeted. (So it's not related to the specific installation). I'm courious as well.

Comment: Have you tried making the constructor public?  I think that might be a requirement.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: Makes no difference. FWIW, the example given above is exactly as it is on one of the linked documentation pages.

Comment: I wasn't sure.  I recall seeing something about C# struct constructor needing to be public and wondered if VB was the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the quoted text below, [Roslyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compiler_Platform) removed support for structures with parameterless constructors, and therefore it's *not* listed as a [new feature in VB 14](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-VB-14).

> It has been a long standing requirement that C# and VB struct
>   constructors would always have parameters. We have tried to relax this
>   requirements in C#6.0 to make structs more consistent with classes.
>
> While overall parameterless constructors in structs are valid from IL
>   perspective, without a convenient way to declare them they were
>   virtually nonexistent. As we performed more and more testing, we kept
>   discovering cases where parameterless struct constructors caused
>   inconsistent behavior in libraries or even in some versions of CLR.
>
> A good example is the issue reported in the CodePlex bug http://roslyn.codeplex.com/workitem/465.  The issue is basically an
>   optimization introduced in Activator.CreateInstance around CLR 4.0 and
>   present ever since. The optimization assumes that parameterless
>   instantiation of generic T type does not cause sideeffects if T is
>   found to be a struct and therefore instances can be cached.
>   Parameterless struct constructors would violate such assumptions and
>   make optimization observable, thus necessitating servicing of existing
>   code several versions back.
>
> After reconsidering the potential issues arising from breaking long
>   standing assumptions, we decided it was best for our users to restore
>   the requirement on struct constructors to always have formal
>   parameters.
>
> ---
>
> Source: [Restore requirement for struct constructors to always have formal parameters. #1029](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1029)

Comment: Its a shame that that particular Roslyn wiki page doesn't appear in search results (for VB 14 or VB 2015 for example) - the one that does is the blog post that links through to the out-of-date list.

Comment: It only mentions C# (6.0). Was VB.NET also changed? Or was it only tried in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Shared Keyword(acts as static) for a Parameter less Constructor in VB.Net.

Try the code below:

```
Structure MyStruct1
   Public Shared f As Integer
   Shared Sub New()
      f = 15
   End Sub
End Structure
Class My_Class
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim str1 As New MyStruct1()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note: `Shared` keyword here acts as static. While using a `Shared Constructor` you need to access `Shared` variables, that is why I have declared the variable with `Shared` keyword.