# Parameterless constructor on struct not supported in C# 6

Tags: c#, struct, constructor, c#-6.0

I have a struct with a parameterless constructor:

```
struct Coordinate
{
    public Coordinate() : this(4, 5, 6)
    {

    }
    public Coordinate(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public float X { get; private set; }
    public float Y { get; private set; }
    public float Z { get; private set; }
}
```

I have the languate property in the project properties set to C#, but an still getting a compile error.

```
Error CS0568 Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors
```

Comment: It has been discussed as a potential C# 6.0 feature, but didn't make it.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @IvanStoev I had read that, but also saw it on [MSDN([https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn879355.aspx).  OK, that clears that up then.  It did sound confusing.

Comment: @JLRishe I did, that being why I was getting the error.  Ivan has cleared it up though.

Comment: @IvanStoev  Do you want to stick that as an answer and I'll tick it?

Comment: See this question discussing the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063109/parameterless-constructors-in-structs-for-c-sharp-6

Comment: @BanksySan No, I can't find official documentation, and too lazy to search Roslyn repository to find when Mads Torgensen (or someone else from dev team) said it will not be included.

Comment: @Phylyp Thanks for the link, I guess we could simply close this a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly C# won't allow defining parameterless constructors.
A workaround for it would be to define a default value, as a property.

```
public static Coordinate defaultValue { get { return new Coordinate (7, 6, 3); } }
```