# At what moment is a c# constructor without parameters initialized?

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm getting some strange errors trying to make use of a vendor dll written probably in another language, and it made me wonder.
For a non static class constructor, at what moment is its constructor called.
Does this happen as soon as new is called (i used to think this).

```
public void initTool()
{ 
    vendorClass x = new vendorClass()
    int i =0;
    i++; ....
```

Or might it perhaps happen earlier in the code like in the main form type definitions, where x could be defined as that vendor class  (thus defining something would trigger constructor code parts to run on beforehand). Perhaps a result of jit optimization or so

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{  
    vendorClass x;  // or vendorClass x=null;
    int i; ...
```

MSDN seams to say that "new" keyword is required in case parameters should be passed into the constructor. However what if it doesnt need that?, in such a case will a dll class constructor be called at the moment of reserving it?.

Note this vendorClass.dll is not in C# written in C++ or plain C, and i dont have the code of it

Comment: "Does this happen as soon as new is called" Yeap. However you could have easily tried this out yourself or simply look into the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/instance-constructors): "Instance constructors are used to create and initialize any instance member variables when you use the **new** expression to create an object of a class. "

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to back up your suspicion that the constructor is called at some time other than when you `new()` an object up? Have you tried recreating the test in your own code, using breakpoints to test? Create a class `Foo` and an empty constructor `public Foo() { /* put some no-op code here so you can breakpoint it*/ }` and then in your `main` class, try declaring it both ways and see what happens.

Comment: It isn't legal for the compiler to run any part of any instance constructor before the `new` (well, not in any way that can be observed, at least), nor does it have any motivation to do so. For `static` constructors the story is completely different, of course.

Comment: Btw.: **Declaring** a variable (in your case by writing `vendorClass x`)  does not "reserve" anything, only **instantiating** does (which is achieved by calling `new ...`).

Comment: @carl Bussema, i dont have the code of this dll, so i cannot insert some test in it. I assume it was written in C, maybe C++ but not in C# (i need to work with buffers and pointers a lot to get it to work) the existence of some types made me wonder if got initialized earlier, that would explain a few things, it could also be that the early initialization has a cause in related in other structs or classes, offered by this dll.

Comment: You could still author your own C or C++ class/struct and try it with breakpoints to see what happens.

Comment: if i was a naked c programmer, yes, i'm into c#

Answer (score 1):

If `vendorClass` is type of `class`:

```
vendorClass x; // constructor is not called, variable x is uninitialized

vendorClass x = new vendorClass(); //constructor is called, x != null
```

There is a difference with `struct` type:

```
vendorClass x; //  all members are default-initialized

vendorClass x = new vendorClass(); // the same
```

Comment: After `vendorClass x;` the variable `x` is [_uninitialized_](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#definite-assignment), **not** `null`. And when `vendorClass` is actually a `struct`, it's not quite accurate to say a "default constructor without parameters [is] called"; [structs cannot have parameterless constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333829) and when constructed this way [all members are default-initialized](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-structs).