# Default initialization of struct records/DUs possible?

Tags: f#

Consider the following definition of `Struct`-annotated record in F#:

```
[<Struct>]
type Foo = Foo of string
```

Or a `Struct`-annotated discriminated union:

```
[<Struct>]
type Bar = { Name : string }
```

If I import these types in C#, I can default construct them:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar();
```

This is because these are value types that have a default constructor. However, this initialization is in C# sometimes implicit and might be surprising. For example:

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[10];
Bar[] bars = new Bar[10];
```

It looks like F# (correctly) prevents me from default initializing these types. At least, the following does not compile:

```
let foo = new Foo()
```

My question is whether there are other scenarios in F# I should be aware of in which a C#-like default initialization as the ones above would be possible for struct records or struct DUs.

Comment: Generally for C# interop it's a good idea not to expose constructors of types, but instead expose functions for creating instances, aka "smart constructors"

Comment: @FyodorSoikin when it comes to types, only expose classes then?

Comment: This is a bit of an ambiguous question, depends on what you mean by "classes". Expose _types_ (either classes or unions or records), but not their _constructors_.

Comment: Although specifically in the case of _classes_ there is no harm in exporting constructors, since you control their signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **CLR** allows for zero-initialization of structs (sometimes inaccurately called default constructors in C#), and for parameterless constructors ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333829/why-cant-i-define-a-default-constructor-for-a-struct-in-net/333840#333840)).

Now that **C#** 10 includes [parameterless constructors](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-10.0/parameterless-struct-constructors.md) this confusing language is being clarified, but the need for backwards compatibility means that you have `new Foo()` referring either to a parameterless constructor or to zero-initialization. This causes the danger in C# which you note.

**F#** [followed the mistake of C#](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1056#issuecomment-895235611) in allowing default initialization via something that looks like construction. This is not the case for DUs and records as you observe but is the case for:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type FooBar(s: string) =
    member _.Value = s
let x = FooBar()
```

As Don Syme notes in that link:

> This is almost never desirable in F# and always somewhat dangerous - and in any case better covered by other language features like `Unchecked.defaultof<Y>`. So we should always have required an attribute opting in to this.

It is planned for F# to move in this direction.