# Value types fields are reference types?

Tags: c#, stack, value-type

I am a bit confused here. With structs, I cannot directly change its fields as the whole struct is of the value type.
But what about classes with value type fields? If I have a public field int X, I can modify it properly. So the only manifestation of value-type nature of its field would be that when passed as an argument, it is a copy?

EDIT: Also

```
Class A
{
  int B=100;  //this is a field, so reference type. But it is a value type.
}
```

The address to content of B is stored on the heap, but is the value of B stored on the stack?

Comment: the question is not 100% clear. Can you provide code sample so we can understand better?

Comment: What makes you think that all fields are reference types?

Answer (score 1):

> With structs, I cannot directly change its fields as the whole struct is of the value type.

You cannot change fields in situations when C# makes a copy of the `struct` for you. In other situations, you can modify fields of a `struct`. Here is a small demonstration of the difference:

```
struct Foo {
    public int A {get;set;}
    public void SetA(int a) {
        A = a;
    }
}

class Bar {
    Foo f;
    public Foo F {
        get{return f;}
        set {f = value;}
    }
    public void SetFooA(int x) {
        f.SetA(x);
    }
}

public static void Main() {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    b.F.SetA(123);  // b.F makes a copy, so changing A fails
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", b.F.A);
    b.SetFooA(456); // Inside Bar, f.SetA is called directly, so the change works fine
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", b.F.A);
    b.F = new Foo { A = 112233 }; // This also works, because the whole F is assigned
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", b.F.A);
}
```

> If I have a public field `int X`, I can modify it properly.

The same rule applies to user-defined `struct`s, as long as you modify the whole of it. You can't modify part of an `int`, because it is not a composite. Modification of a `struct` works fine when you assign the whole `struct` at once. In other words, assigning

```
b.F = new Foo { A = 112233 };
```

in my example replaces assigning

```
B = 100;
```

in your example.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/raNfHq)

Answer (score 0):

> The address to content of B is stored on the heap, but is the value of B stored on the stack?

No. Value type fields of a class are stored on the heap.

Please refer to @Marc Gravell's answer here for more information about this:

[Why value-types are stored onto Stacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932155/why-value-types-are-stored-onto-stacks)

You may also want to read @Eric Lippert's blog post on the subject: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/

In short value types *can* be stored on the stack but they are not always stored on the stack.

Answer (score -1):

Struct gives you a copy of the original field because a copy of the struct would be passed. Changing it to class would pass a reference to the class and therefore the field would modify if you were to change it.