# When should I use a struct?

Tags: .net, class, struct

If I have a class and it's essentially just a bunch of variables - has no methods, really more of a storage space - is it better to convert it to a struct?

What is the "rule" for when to use a struct and when to use a class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use a struct instead of a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203695 could be helpful too..

Answer (score 2):

Rule number one is that it should not be larger than 16 bytes.  Typically 4 fields.  The jitter generated code takes a nasty nosedive when it gets larger than that.  That's not compatible with "bunch of variables".  There's nothing wrong with a simple class.

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb is when the entity represents a value (and thus is immutable) and doesn't have identity (for example, two instances of "5" are the same).  Hence, you should override `==` as well as `.Equals.`  `String`, for example, is a class only for pragmatic reasons.  Similarly, don't use a struct for more than a handful of fields.  Probably it could be further decomposed.

Answer (score 1):

-the member and inheritance of a class is private by default while those are public in struct.

-Use a class when object identity is more important than value. Use a struct when the value contained by an instance is more important than instance identity.

-Structures are value types; classes are reference types.

-A structure must have at least one nonshared variable or event member. a class can be completely empty.

-if you need to handle event use class.

-class use heap allocation while stack use stack allocation

-if u need to initialized any member value then use class because you cant do this in stack.

i think now u can understand the differences. now u can use stack or class according to your need.

thanks
arefin

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx .  Particularly the part that reads, "The access level for class members and struct members, including nested classes and structs, is private by default."  Don't confuse C#'s (or .net's) definition of `struct` with C++'s.

Comment: Also, structs can have constructors.  They just can't have *default* (parameterless) constructors.

Answer (score 1):

From [Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321658701)

> Value types or reference types?
>   Structs or classes? When should you
>   use each? This isn’t C++, in which you
>   define all types as value types and
>   can create references to them. This
>   isn’t Java, in which everything is a
>   reference type (unless you are one of
>   the language designers). You must
>   decide how all instances of your type
>   will behave when you create it. It’s
>   an important decision to get right the
>   first time. You must live with the
>   consequences of your decision because
>   changing later can cause quite a bit
>   of code to break in subtle ways. It’s
>   a simple matter of choosing the struct
>   or class keyword when you create the
>   type, but it’s much more work to
>   update all the clients using your type
>   if you change it later.
>
> It’s not as simple as preferring one
>   over the other. The right choice
>   depends on how you expect to use the
>   new type. Value types are not
>   polymorphic. They are better suited to
>   storing the data that your application
>   manipulates. Reference types can be
>   polymorphic and should be used to
>   define the behavior of your
>   application. Consider the expected
>   responsibilities of your new type, and
>   from those responsibilities, decide
>   which type to create. Structs store
>   data. Classes define behavior.

From [C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471)

> Suppose you’re reading something
>   fantastic, and want a friend to read
>   it too. Let’s further suppose that
>   it’s a document in the public domain,
>   just to avoid any accusations of
>   supporting copyright violation. What
>   do you need to give your friend so
>   that he can read it too? It depends
>   entirely on what you’re reading.
>
> First we’ll deal with the case where
>   you have real paper in your hands. To
>   give your friend a copy, you’d need to
>   photocopy all the pages and then give
>   it to him. At that point, he has his
>   own complete copy of the document. In
>   this situation, we’re dealing with
>   value type behavior. All the
>   information is directly in your
>   hands—you don’t need to go anywhere
>   else to get it. Your copy of the
>   information is also independent of
>   your friend’s after you’ve made the
>   copy. You could add some notes to your
>   pages, and his pages wouldn’t be
>   changed at all.
>
> Compare that with the situation where
>   you’re reading a web page. This time,
>   all you have to give your friend is
>   the URL of the web page. This is
>   reference type behavior, with the URL
>   taking the place of the reference. In
>   order to actually read the document,
>   you have to navigate the reference by
>   putting the URL in your browser and
>   asking it to load the page. On the
>   other hand, if the web page changes
>   for some reason (imagine it’s a wiki
>   page and you’ve added your notes to
>   the page), both you and your friend
>   will see that change the next time
>   each of you loads the page.
>
> The differences we’ve seen in the real
>   world form the heart of the
>   distinction between value types and
>   reference types in C# and .NET. Most
>   types in .NET are reference types, and
>   you’re likely to create far more
>   reference than value types. The most
>   common cases to know are that classes
>   (declared using class) are reference
>   types, and structures (declared using
>   struct) are value types. The other
>   situations are as follows:
>
> Array types are reference types, even
>   if the element type is a value type
>   (so int[] is still a reference type,
>   even though int is a value type).
>
> Enumerations (declared using enum) are
>   value types.
>
> Delegate types (declared using
>   delegate) are reference types.
>
> Interface types (declared using
>   interface) are reference types, but
>   they can be implemented by value
>   types.
>
> Now that we have a basic idea of what
>   reference types and value types are
>   about, we’ll look at a few of the most
>   important details.

Answer (score 0):

See... [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> Structs vs. Classes
>
> Structs may seem similar to classes,
>   but there are important differences
>   that you should be aware of. First of
>   all, classes are reference types and
>   structs are value types. By using
>   structs, you can create objects that
>   behave like the built-in types and
>   enjoy their benefits as well.
>
> Heap or Stack?
>
> When you call the New operator on a
>   class, it will be allocated on the
>   heap. However, when you instantiate a
>   struct, it gets created on the stack.
>   This will yield performance gains.
>   Also, you will not be dealing with
>   references to an instance of a struct
>   as you would with classes. You will be
>   working directly with the struct
>   instance. Because of this, when
>   passing a struct to a method, it's
>   passed by value instead of as a
>   reference.

So if you are using the data only in a method and are not passing it around to functions then a struct can give you performance gains as it is only allocated on the stack... if you are going to pass it around to a bunch of function then a class is probably better because it would be passed around by reference and not "copied" over and over...

Comment: It is a misleading article.  Better is to look at Eric Lippert's blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx.  The fact that it's heap or stack is *not* what you should focus on with struct/class, it's pass-by-value or pass-by-reference.

Comment: value type = on stack...     reference type = on heap...  struct is on the stack.. and therefore a value type... and therefore passed by value... ok not really a rule as asked for but I though getting at the actual reasons might help...

Comment: I read the article and now understand what you are talking about.  We should focus on semantic meaning of struct vs class not the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Structs are generally used for small amounts of data that represent a single, cohesive unit of information.  They're usually passed around by value, which involves passing a copy of it rather than a reference to the object itself.

This means that structs have a couple of minor gotchas.  If

- the data will have value semantics -- that is, if the object could be cloned without causing issues, and what matters is the values and not their identities;
- the total amount of data will be less than about 16 bytes, since the runtime will end up copying it around rather than just passing a reference; and
- if it's immutable, since modifying a copy generally won't modify the original;

then you may do well to use a struct.

If any of those aren't true, you may want to consider keeping the class as a class.

Comment: @Mark So you couldn't `Foo(ref myStruct);` ?

Comment: @Mark: `public void NotAlways(ref PassedByReference example)`.

Comment: 16 bytes of data? isn't that quite small? like 4 integers?

Comment: @Robo: Yes, it's pretty small.  You don't want to have much in a struct, as the runtime copies all those bytes whenever it passes the struct to a method.  Past 16 bytes or so, that gets to be a lot of copying, making structs less suitable.