# Where and why use int a=new int?

Tags: c#, new-operator

Just curious, what is the difference between:

```
int A = 100;
```

and

```
int A = new int();
```

I know new is used to allocate memory on the heap..but I really do not get the context here.

Comment: To be simple enough...,    int A=100; is simply declaring an int var A and initialising it to 100..,
whereas int A= new int();  is an error   .,Although it could be..
 int *A = new int(); which means create space for an int on stack put 0 in it and return address of that int to integer pointer,i.e  A

Comment: @eRaisedToX It is not an error to use new operator with a value type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563774/dilemma-with-using-value-types-with-new-operator-in-c-sharp It basically does nothing observable. And the tag is for C# not C++.

Answer (score 36):

```
static void Main()
{
    int A = new int();
    int B = default(int);
    int C = 100;
    Console.Read();
}
```

Is compiled to

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       15 (0xf)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] int32 A,
           [1] int32 B,
           [2] int32 C)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0004:  stloc.1
  IL_0005:  ldc.i4.s   100
  IL_0007:  stloc.2
  IL_0008:  call       int32 [mscorlib]System.Console::Read()
  IL_000d:  pop
  IL_000e:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

As you can see first one just initialize it and second one is **just the same** and third one initialize and set to `100`. As for the IL code generated, **they both get initialized in a single line**.

so

```
int A = new int();
```

Is the same as

```
int A = default(int);
```

Comment: is it also the same as 'int a;' ?

Answer (score 22):

Difference?

the latter ends with A being 0, not 100.

When?

Pretty much never. Maybe in some generated code it is simpler to use the `new TypeName()` syntax, but `default(TypeName)` would be preferred even then.

And `new` does ***not*** "allocate memory on the heap". It initializes an instance; that is all.

Comment: SO there is no meaning in the new keyword?

Comment: Unless you want an instance of the object/structure and not just the default/null value.

Comment: @Miriah - there is meaning: it means we want to initialize a new object or value; it just doesn't strictly mean anything to do with heap or stack. Note that `new` has an alternative usage (as a keyword) in method hiding. Completely unrelated, but it exists.

Answer (score 10):

I strongly recommend that you read this article from dotnet mob: http://codaffection.blogspot.in/2015/02/difference-between-declarations-int-i.html

```
int A = 100; //Initialises A to 100 manually
```

Suppose you declare an integer as

```
int A;
```

For further operations on `A`, you need to initialise `A` with an integer value, otherwise the compiler shows

> **use of unassigned local variable**

To declare `A` as follows

```
int A = new int(); //A initialised to 0 (default value of int)
```

allows for further operations on A without a manual initialisation - I think you get my point now.

---

Now let's discuss using `new ()`.

Use of `new` doesn't mean memory will be allocated on the heap; if `A` is a local variable (e.g. in a method) it will be allocated memory on the stack.
If A is a member of a class however, then memory *will* be allocated on the heap when an instance of the class is created.

**Point to be remembered: if A is static, it will always be on stack memory!**

Comment: I like this explanation, but what then is the difference between initializing a variable with "int x = 0" versus"int x = new()"?

Comment: @Stokely int x= 0 vs int x = new int();  no difference in both case x will initialised to zero.

Answer (score 9):

```
int A=100;
```

Allocates an int on the stack and sets its value to 100.

```
int A=new int();
```

Allocates an int on the stack (yes, value types are always allocated on the stack, even with the `new` keyword) and sets its value to the default, that is, 0.

Comment: The "value types on the stack" is misleading. For example, in an array-of-structs, or as a field on a class. It also depends how you count a "unit on the stack then copy"

Comment: you said *always*... always is not "this precise case"

Comment: Always is incorrect, if the int is a local var, then it will be on the stack, but if it's an instance field then it will be on the heap.

Answer (score 6):

I saw it from another link:

MSDN says "The new operator is also used to invoke the default constructor for value types."

Inside a method:

- `int x;`: allocates an int on stack and does not initialize it.
- `int x=5;`: allocates an int on stack and sets it to 5;
- `int x=new int();`: allocates an int on stack and sets it to 0;
- `int x=new int(5);`: does not compile.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
myInt = new int();  // Invoke default constructor for int type.
```

This statement is equivalent to the following statement:

```
myInt = 0;         // Assign an initial value, 0 in this example.
```

Using the new operator calls the default constructor of the specific type and assigns the default value to the variable. The default value of an integer is 0 BTW.

The difference is that you can't initialize and set anything but the default value value using the new operator.

Comment: They are not the same. See my comments.

Comment: Initializing Value Types :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx
also in my reading, as 0 is the default value of an int, that's why myInt = default(int) and myInt = 0 are going to be the same.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions about using "new" and "default". Their use is pointless. It seems its much better to always instantiate a value type to a default value you choose, even if its 0, so its always available. You also avoid confusion as to what its custom default should be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is necessary to add new on int(because int has default memory size)..
new is used when we have a user-defined class of which we instantiate an object..

```
public static Main()
{
  Cat cat1=new Cat();
}

Public class Cat
{
  public bool Sex
  public string Name
}
```

Now compiler will allocate that much memory to cat1(memory size which is defined in class Cat)

Answer (score 0):

"int" is a value type, so neither expression will allocate memory on the managed heap.  The first statement will initialize A to the literal you specify.  The second statement will leave A at a default value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the int as a field in your class, you might even say simply `int x;` - since int is a value type it cannot be null and therefore gets its default value - i.e. 0.

Answer (score 0):

I end up discovering my problem

I was modifying the values but not the Object

This is the proper way to do it :

```
 public ActionResult ChangeDefaultUserLockingSetting(int PasswordAttempts, int DefaultLockingTime)
        {
            var defaultAccountSettings = new DefaultAccountSettingsDataContext();

            var accountSettings = defaultAccountSettings.DefaultAccountSettings.First(u => u.id == 1);


            accountSettings.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = DefaultLockingTime;
            accountSettings.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = PasswordAttempts;

            defaultAccountSettings.SubmitChanges();
            return View("Index", loadAdministrationViewModel());
        }
```