# Difference between "0" and "new int()" in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why use int a=new int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746873/where-and-why-use-int-a-new-int)

What's the difference between these two below?

```
int i =0; 
int i = new int();
```

Is there any difference in case of memory allocation ?
Is there any other difference?

Comment: implicit and explicit declarations of variable "i".

Comment: @Mullaly -- how so? (FWIW: `0 == new int() == default(int)`)

Comment: The first one is obviously unambiguous, even to the casual reader.

Comment: new int().. goes through the construcuor of int32 class.

Comment: @Mullaly No, it doesn't. System.Int32 is a "special" *structure* type, along with the other primitives. Just because it doesn't have the same awkward separation as Java doesn't mean the bytecode doesn't treat it special/efficiently! (Compare with `1+2` or other such operations.)

Comment: @pst..Thanks for enlightment.!

Answer (score 5):

Both of them compiles to same thing.

Suppose you have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = new int();

    Console.Write("{0}{1}", i, j);
}
```

If you build in Release mode and see the executable in [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), it compiles to:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      Console.Write("{0}{1}", i, j);
}
```

`new int()` is same as `default(int)`

Here is the IL

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       27 (0x1b)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] int32 i,
           [1] int32 j)
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0001:  stloc.0
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0003:  stloc.1
  IL_0004:  ldstr      "{0}{1}"
  IL_0009:  ldloc.0
  IL_000a:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_000f:  ldloc.1
  IL_0010:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0015:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::Write(string,
                                                            object,
                                                            object)
  IL_001a:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one

```
int i = 0;
```

Initialize a new integer of name `i`. Then, sets its value to `0`

While the second one

```
int i = new int();
```

Initializes a new integer of name `i` to the default value (which is `0`). This is also similar to

```
int i = default(int);
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: In all cases the value is set to 0.  It does more than just allocate space for the variable and create the symbol table entry.

Comment: @tvanfosson I agree with you. There's no difference but I just wanted to illustrate what each does. It won't be the same in case the value changes :)

Comment: int i = new int(); this also sets as 0.

Comment: The phrase "without doing anything else" is misleading then.  You seem to be saying that in the second case it doesn't set the value of the memory location, but C# will initialize it to the default value, 0.

Comment: @JobyKurian Yes. Since you did not set a particular value, the value will be set automatically to zero. So that you'll have a defined variable. The same also happens with other structs such as `float`/`double`/etc... Have a great day :)

Comment: @tvanfosson By "without doing anything else" I meant that the value will be *default-ly* initialized and by initialized I mean that the value will be set to `0` if the programmer did not specify a specific value for the `int`. I did not mean that the value will not be set to `0` in case there's no specific input. Have a great day :)

Comment: I've changed the phrase to more accurately reflect what you've stated in your comments.