# in C#, why not use 'new' keyword when declaring an int?

Tags: c#, int

When declaring an int..

```
int A = 10;
```

why not do the following instead?

```
int A = new Int()
A=10;
```

are both the same?

Comment: The former creates less objects, is clearer and more efficient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why use int a=new int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746873/where-and-why-use-int-a-new-int)

Answer (score 12):

Because [`int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int) is syntax sugar for [`Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32) which is a value type. Incidentally, so is the constant value `10` (an instance of the [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) [Int32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32)). That's why you don't need to use [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator) to create a new instance, but rather making a copy of `10` and calling it `A`. And similar syntax works with reference types as well, but with the difference that a copy isn't made; a reference is created.

Essentially, you can think of `10` as a previously declared instance of [`Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32). Then `int A = 10` is just setting variable A to a **copy** of value `10` (if we were talking about [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) then A would be set to a reference to the instance instead of a copy).

To better illustrate here's another example:

```
struct SomeValueType {
    public SomeValueType(){        
    }
}

public static readonly SomeValueType DEFAULT = new SomeValueType();
```

Then you can just do this:

```
SomeValueType myValueType = DEFAULT;  // no neeed to use new!
```

Now imagine that `SomeValueType` is `Int32` and `DEFAULT` is `10`. There it is!

Comment: System.Int32 not Integer :)

Comment: Isn't this crating an object? In Java `Long` is an object and `long` is a primitive.

Comment: In .Net all primitive types are treated as objects. Creating an object is not a big deal, especially if it's a small-sized primitive type which the CLR is optimized to work with..

Comment: @MikyDinescu That's a very confusing thing to say. What does it mean to be treated as object? What exactly is a primitive type?

Comment: Also, when it comes to these kinds of questions, it pays to be very precise: `10` is not a value type, it's an *instance* of a value type.

Comment: @svick - that's precisely what I said: _ think of 10 as a previously declared instance of Int32_

Comment: @MikyDinescu But you're saying something else int the first paragraph.

Comment: @svick - hmm.. I've reread that and I can see how that might be interpreted wrong. I'll edit.

Answer (score 9):

You may have seen Java, where `int` and `Integer` are two different things, and the latter requires you to write `new Integer(10)`.

In C# `int` is a special alias for `Int32`, and for all intents and purposes they are the same. Indeed, to create a new instance of any type you'd have to write `new Int32()` or something.

However, because integers are primitive types in C# (and most programming languages), there is a special syntax for integer literals. Just writing `10` makes it an `Int32` (or `int`).

In your example you are actually assigning a value to the `a` variable twice:

```
int a = new Int32();  // First assignment, a equals 0
a = 10;               // Second assignment, a equals 10
```

You might imagine that since the second assignment overwrites the first, the first assignment is not required.

Answer (score 9):

In C# there are two kinds of types, "reference types" and "value types".  (Pointers are a third kind of type but let's not get into that.)

When you use the default constructor of a value type, all you are saying is "give me the default value of this value type". So `new int()` is neither more nor less than just saying `0`.

So your program is the same as:

```
int i = 0;
i = 10;
```

Comment: Why didn't the C# designer define an additional ctor for it such that we can invoke `int i=new int(10);` without having to set to 0 first?

Answer (score 0):

if you write youe code like

```
int A = new Int();
```

the variable 'A' is assigned by the default value of int, so you can use variable 'A' without assigning a value to it(in `c#` we cant use a variable without assigning a value to it)
when using the keyword new it will automatically call the default constructor, it will assign default values to the variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
int A = new Int();
```

It declares and initializes `A` to `0`.

Basically, the new operator here is used to invoke the default constructor for value types. For the type int, the default value is 0.

It has the same effect as the following:

```
int A = 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For the next time please take a look to the markdowns :)

Comment: Basically, the new operator here is used to invoke the default constructor for value types. For int type, the default value is 0.

Comment: Int is not a valid .NET type. Either use new Int32() or new int()