# Difference between int and new int()

Tags: c#

I didn't understand the actual use of new int()

So my qustion is what is the difference between

```
int myNumber = 5;
```

and

```
int myNumber = new int();
```

What is the best use of new int() or when should we use new int()
I know the memory allocation difference (stack and heap) but i didn't find any actual use of new int()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746873/where-and-why-use-int-a-new-int

Comment: There is no memory allocation difference

Comment: "I know the memory allocation difference (stack and heap)" Do you? See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746873/where-and-why-use-int-a-new-int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int myNumber;

int myNumber = 0;

int myNumber = new int();
```

The effect should be exactly the same, you can try to ILDASM them if you're doubtful

Comment: What type of answer is this...

Answer (score 0):

Never use `new int();`.
Always use:

```
int myNumber = 5;
```

There is no difference between the two of them. But you should never instintiate your value types with the 'new' keyword.

```
bool myBool = new bool(); // <== just looks odd, right?
```

Comment: I just want to ask, why?

Comment: Even if there is a difference, as pointed out by others. The difference is so tiny you should not bother about 4 Bytes (an integer), except if you're programming for micro processors.
Instead you should bother about readability of your written code.

Comment: There are times, especially in generic programming, where you might well be doing a `new int()` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

```
int myNumber = new int();
```

is equivalent to:

```
int myNumber = 0;
```