# Best Way to read the following xml format

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I have a xml file with the following format :

```
<list name="a">
<person>        
    <field name="Name">aaa</field>
    <field name="lname">bb'b'</field>
    <field name="tel">123</field>
    <field name="tel">1234</field>
    <field name="tel">12345</field>
</person>
<person>        
    <field name="Name">vvv</field>
    <field name="lname">fff'</field>
    <field name="tel">1</field>
    <field name="tel">2</field>
    <field name="tel">3</field>
</person>
<person>        
    <field name="Name">ccc</field>
    <field name="lname">bb:'c'</field>
    <field name="tel">4</field>
    <field name="tel">5</field>
    <field name="tel">6</field>
</person>
</list>
```

and the following struct :

```
struct person
{
string name;
string lname;
string[] tel;
}
```

I got confused between different methods to read and write xml with following format
I did my best to try methods T but not the result I wanted

I want to :

- read the file and put the contents to struct array or dataTable to show in gridView.
- write dataTable or Struct to a file with exacly same format as the input

I did my best to try methods , but not the result I wanted
also  the xmlWriter doesn't escape the ' and " in values like :

```
bb&apos;b&apos; instead of bb'b'
```

I tried following methods :
xmlserializer
xmlReader
xmlWriter
generating text manualy

Comment: Can you please clarify this part of question: *"I did my best to try methods , but not the result I wanted"*? What methods did you try? Which results are wanted? What you actually got?

Comment: so what did you try so far?  Why not post the code that isn't working as expected?

Comment: If you have a fixed struct why do you have a dynamic xml file?

Comment: Also read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620843/does-it-make-sense-to-define-a-struct-with-a-reference-type-member Answer: you should probably be using a class.

Comment: To read it, use `XmlDocument`, load the file then loop on rows with `SelectNode`.

Comment: Can you share your code?