# Does a struct with an array filed make sense?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I've the following struct with an array as second field:

```
public struct UncNumber
{
    private double _value;
    private DependsOn[] _dependencies;

    public double Value { get { return _value; } }
    public DependsOn[] Dependencies { get { return _dependencies; } }

    public UncNumber(double value, DependsOn[] dependencies)
    {
        _value = value;
        _dependencies = dependencies;
    }
}
```

By the way the `DependsOn` struct looks like that:

```
public struct DependsOn
{
    private int _input;
    private double _jacobi;

    public int Input { get { return _input; } }
    public double Jacobi { get { return _jacobi; } }

    public DependsOn(int input, double jacobi)
    {
        _input = input;
        _jacobi = jacobi;
    }
}
```

I looked at the following resources:

- [What's the difference between struct and class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)
- [When should I use a struct instead of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Does it make sense to define a struct with a reference type member?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5620843/7556646)

But I didn't came to a conclusion yet if I should use a struct or a class for `UncNumber`. I've the following additional comments why I think a struct is the better choice in this case:

- I'm using the above `UncNumber` structure for mathematical computation, similiar like I could use the [Complex Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.110).aspx.).
- I'm having a lot of methods which use arrays of the `UncNumber` struct. E.g.: matrix multiplication  `UncNumber[,] Dot(UncNumber[,] a, UncNumber[,] b)`.
- A lot of the instances of the `UncNumber` struct will be very short-lived and immutable.
- The instance size of the `UncNumber` struct is 16 bytes (8 bytes for the double Value and 8 bytes for the reference type / array Dependencies).

Or does a struct with an array field not make sense at all?

Comment: `A lot of the instances of the UncNumber struct will be very short-lived and immutable.` The type is most certainly not immutable.  You have public fields.  They can be mutated.

Comment: @Servy I could have private fields, readonly properties and a constructor `UncNumber(double value, DependsOn[] dependencies)`. So it should be immutable.

Comment: Yes, you could make it immutable by doing that.  Note that `DependsOn` is also currently mutable, when it really shouldn't be.  Also note that if you return the array from `UncNumber`, even if you don't let the array *variable* be mutated, the returned array is mutable and could be mutated.  To make the type properly immutable you'd need to return a read-only collection of some type (i.e. `IEnumerable<T>` or `IReadOnlyList<T>`, depending on what you need).

Comment: @Sery I'm aware about the immutable stuff. I just wrote the code in post like that for simplification. Should I edit my code in the question?

Comment: If your actual structs are immutable, then yes, you should edit the question to reflect that, as it's a highly relevant difference.

Comment: @Sery I've edited the question. I'm not using `public ReadOnlyCollection<DependsOn> Dependencies { get { return Array.AsReadOnly(_dependencies) ; } }` because the read only wrapper for the array will slow done stuff, because an additional instance for the wrapper has to be created.

Comment: I mentioned two options for a read only operation that don't require a new instance.  But either way, if you aware that the type is mutable in that way, that's your decision.  As the struct itself isn't mutable it avoids *most* of the problems, but it is still somewhat unexpected for a struct to expose a reference to a mutable object.

Comment: @Sery Either if I'm implementing `IEnumerable<T>` or I'm using `IReadOnlyList<T>` wrapper there will be an array behind to store the data. So there a two instance of reference types. One for the array the other for the class implementing `IEnumerable<T>` or the wrapper class `IReadOnlyList<T>`. On the other hand If I'm just using the array there is just one instance of a reference type, the array itself. That's the reason why it's faster. I'm aware that the array is mutable but I'm just using it readonly.

Comment: You don't need a wrapper.  Arrays implement both of those interfaces.