# Is it better to pass around whole models or just identifiers?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, model, godot

I often find myself passing (data-)models around to where ever I need them, down the hierarchy as method parameters, and up the hierarchy as event parameters.

An illustrative example would be me loading a bunch of data-items from disk to set up a stack of (mouse-)draggable items. Now, the stack holds an array of data-models. If the user clicks and drags an item from the stack, a visual drag-object is set up and given the respective model. When the item is being dropped, the drag-object sends an event with  the position where it has been dropped and said model as parameters, which then gets passed to the receiver, if there is any at the position. And so on ...

I always wonder if this is the clean and efficient way to do this, to pass around whole models, or if instead I should just pass an identifier (like a Guid) and have objects/classes who actually need the data look it up in some form of globally accessible database.

Is there any best practice or pattern to this?

(Context for me is game development in C#, Unity and Godot)

Comment: while this is fairly opinion-based, in .NET objects are allways just passed by reference. So whenever you feel like "passing an entire model around", you actually just pass a reference to it, making the memory-footprint neglectable.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, that actually was part of what I suspected and wondered about but wasn't entirely sure. You're right, everything else is probably down to personal preference, but I'm still curious if anyone got strong opinions about this.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain this only applies if the objects are already in the memory. If the objects are only on disk and get loaded individually instead of having them all in the stack, you would save some memory at the cost of greater latency.
The "correct" answer to OPs question depends on the exact scenario, but let me drop this quote "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain that only applies to class/reference types of course ;) So basically you could say OP's question boils down to: [When should I use class and when struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5621610/7111561) which especially regarding `I often find myself passing (data-)models around to where ever I need them, down the hierarchy as method parameters, and up the hierarchy as event parameters.` is basically already answered then ^^

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to passing a data blob is to centralise it. Unity has a built in system for script independent data storage called [Scriptable Objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) which are well worth looking into. Used creatively they can also facilitate events and other class-shared features (see also the key talk on the subject from [the Unite conference, Austin 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3iHhE_Kk)).

Comment: is mostly quite an antipattern as well though ... in OP's question it somewhat comes down to the same ... SO are classes and thereby passed by reference (aka identifiers)

Comment: @derHugo I think for a lot of data in Unity SOs are more maintainable, easier to read and maintain etc. OPs question is also one of utility IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it depends.

It depends on various factors, such as the size of your objects, the number of accesses, and the complexity of the logic.

Trivially, if you have small objects that are frequently read or written it definitely pays to pass them as an entire object.
On the other hand, if you have very large objects and the reads are sporadic, perhaps it is better at this point to use an identifier type and read it as needed to avoid multiple database accesses.

Certainly a logic by reference in any case can help to have a good compromise between the two.

I hope it can help you choose the best approach.

Comment: Thank you! That feels like a good approach indeed. Whole objects when small, references when big!

However, could you please explain what you meant by: "Certainly a logic by reference in any case can help to have a good compromise between the two.". What do you mean by "logic by reference"?

Comment: Yes, sorry you are right, it is not clear actually. D:
I meant that using references is still a good way to do it, regardless of the size. Of course, if you don't have to read from the database.
The word "compromise" was not the best way to define it.