# StackOverflowException when comparing dates

Tags: c#, datetime, properties, struct, stack-overflow

I have an DateTime property field in a struct. I'm trying to validate the inputdate to make sure the value entered is not in the future.

i'm using the following code:

```
public struct Car
{
    public DateTime Year
    {
        get
        {
            return Year;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value > DateTime.Now)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Date cannot be in the futrure");
            else
                Year = value;
        }
    }
}
```

When i now try to run this code i keep getting a StackOverflowException with the message "Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state."

any ideas on why this is, or how to fix this?

-Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a good reason for using a struct?

Comment: @ChaosPandion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203695/structure-vs-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson - I'm pretty sure I've read that question at some point. My intent is actually to understand why they chose to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling a property called `Year`, whose `get` accessor calls `Year`, whose `get` accessor calls `Year`... and so on, and so forth, until your stack overflows.

You should create a private field, `private DateTime _year`, to store the actual value.

Answer (score 5):

It's returning itself... try setting a variable.

```
public struct Car 
{ 
    private DateTime _year;
    public DateTime Year 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _year; 
        } 

        set 
        { 
            if (value > DateTime.Now) 
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Date cannot be in the futrure"); 
            else 
                _year = value; 
        } 
    } 
}
```