# performance and memory optimization (class vs struct)

Tags: c#, .net, struct

I am starting to work on a polygon library, whose side are bezier curves. The basic don't quite work yet so I can't really write stress / performance test program yet. nor show much code.

At any rate I have classes like that

```
public class BezierFragment
{
    Point2D[] controlPoints; // length: 2, 3 or 4
}
public struct Point2D { public double X, Y; }
```

But I am wondering  whether I should instead use struct (for less heap allocation and more stack copies)

```
public struct BezierFragment
{
    byte order; // 2, 3, or 4
    Point2D p0, p1, p2, p3;
}
public struct Point2D { public double X, Y; }
```

The later is much easier on the memory management, but might require more copy (of 65 bytes) struct. I wonder which one would be best. 
How would I figure out the best option?

The (possible) memory management issues of the first choice might only be apparent when lots of Point2D[] array are saved in generation 2 memory pool and then destroyed...

Any tip?

Comment: **[Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)**

Comment: Excellent link, thanks! :)

Comment: Your class and sruct examples here are different things anyway so you can't really compare them.

Comment: DavidG, I am not sure what confuse you....BezierFragment is always a 2-3-or-4 points thing, and I just highlighted a class and struct version for what is essentially the same information. I dunno what you saw... But you didn't see the right thing, obviously...

Answer (score 4):

**Given**

```
class Foo : Attribute
{
   public int I { get; set; }
}

struct Foo2 
{
   public int I { get; set; }
}
```

**And**

```
private static void Method1(Foo foo)
{
   foo.I = 1;
}
private static void Method2(Foo2 foo2)
{
   foo2.I = 1;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var foo = new Foo();
//IL_0001: newobj       instance void ConsoleApp3.Foo::.ctor()
//IL_0006: stloc.0      // foo

var foo2 = new Foo2();
//IL_0007: ldloca.s     foo2
//IL_0009: initobj      ConsoleApp3.Foo2

Method1(foo);
//IL_0000: nop          
//IL_0001: ldarg.0      // foo
//IL_0002: ldc.i4.1     
//IL_0003: callvirt     instance void ConsoleApp3.Foo::set_I(int32)
//IL_0008: nop          
//IL_0009: ret   

Method2(foo2);
//IL_0000: nop          
//IL_0001: ldarga.s     foo2
//IL_0003: ldc.i4.1     
//IL_0004: call         instance void ConsoleApp3.Foo2::set_I(int32)
//IL_0009: nop          
//IL_000a: ret
```

Not a lot going on there

---

However, if you want to know what goes on the heap there is a bit more to the story

[Memory usage in .NET when creating a new class or struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402787/memory-usage-in-net-when-creating-a-new-class-or-struct)

> A single reference either takes 4 bytes on 32-bit processes or 8 bytes
>   on 64-bit processes. A reference is a standard overhead on classes (as
>   they are reference types). Structs do not incur references (well,
>   ignoring any potential boxing) and are the size of their content
>   usually. I cannot remember if classes have any more overhead, don't
>   think so.

[Does using “new” on a struct allocate it on the heap or stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203695/does-using-new-on-a-struct-allocate-it-on-the-heap-or-stack)

Also as already pointed out, there are more considerations

Some more reading

[Coding for performance: Struct vs Class](https://curryncode.com/2016/09/28/coding-for-performance-struct-vs-class/)

---

**Even Further reading**

[Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)

> ✓ **CONSIDER** defining a struct instead of a class if instances of the
>   type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in
>   other objects.

**More so**

> X **AVOID** defining a struct unless the type has all of the following
>   characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types
>     (int, double, etc.).
> - It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.
>
> In all other cases, you should define your types as classes.

Since your interested in performance, look at this as well

[Writing Faster Managed Code: Know What Things Cost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx)