# Why value type fields may be instantiated, instead of initialized?

Tags: .net, clr, cil

A value type local variable (e.g. `S s;` given `struct S{}`) is initialized though the invocation of its constructor (e.g. `a = new S(11)`), if `S` declares a constructor with `int` parameter. Then `new S(11)` compiles to:

```
ldloca.s   V_0
ldc.i4.s   11
call       instance void S::.ctor(int32)
```

However when `s` is a field (e.g. `class C { S s;`), then it is not initialized in the same way. Regarding the following instance method of class `C`: `void setS(int n) { s = new S(n);  }` it will compile to:

```
ldarg.0
ldarg.1
newobj     instance void S::.ctor(int32)
stfld      valuetype S C::s
```

I was expecting that it would compile to the following code, which is more close to the case of a local variable:

```
ldarg.0
ldflda    valuetype S C::s
ldarg.1
call       instance void S::.ctor(int32)
```

Moreover, if I am clearly understanding, the `newobj     instance void S::.ctor(int32)` has higher overhead and burdens GC. Am I correct?

Why, C# compiler uses for value type fields a different approach than used for local variables?

Comment: As Jon's correct answer notes, the optimization cannot be performed if the optimized version could produce different observable behaviour than the unoptimized version. FYI this optimization is called a "copy elision" and is common in C++ compilers; if you want to learn more about it, now you know a search term you can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this behaviour is required in order to separate the constructor call from the assignment.

The expected observable behaviour is that if a constructor throws an exception, the assignment doesn't take place. That won't be the case in the "optimized" version where the constructor writes directly to the field/stack slot.

You can see the same IL when assigning to a local variable if:

- The variable was already declared and assigned before
- The variable is still accessible if an exception is thrown

Not quite the same question, but there's more detail [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204009/22656) and on [Eric Lippert's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/10/11/debunking-another-myth-about-value-types/).