# What is the cost comparison of allocating memory for a reference type vs. a value type in the CLR?

Tags: c#, memory-management, struct, clr

Numerous times I have come across allusions to the effect that allocating an object is expensive.

Most references are either:

1. oblique, or
2. are incomplete in that they explain no further as to specifically *what* that cost is and how it compares to anything that isn't an object, either because the reference is contextual and wants to get on with the main topic it is discussing or is outright dishonest.
3. Or it is that the references leave out by implication what it is they are comparing the cost of allocating memory for an object with. Okay, creating an object is expensive, but *against what*? And why? And how? And how much?

I cannot find all the references I have come across in the past but one sudden occurrence has given way to my motivation (and accompanying frustration) to ask this question. It isn't an authoritative source but here it goes:

**Example 1**

[This article](https://www.dotnetperls.com/struct) on `structs` says:

> With structs you avoid the overhead of objects in the C# language. You
>   can combine multiple fields. This reduces memory pressure. And it
>   (sometimes) improves performance.

Now, I have *no idea* what this is talking about. Sure, even the simplest object in the CLR takes up 12 bytes as follows:

1. 4 bytes for something I forget, I presume some kind of a header;
2. 4 bytes for a pointer to the object's method table; and
3. 4 bytes for the first field the object contains, even if the object contains no fields or properties.

Are `struct`s and value types laid out differently? Surely, `struct`s also must have a method table and a header. Then what is the comparative cost of declaring a `struct` as against an object? Or for that matter, what is the cost comparison of allocating an object as against declaring *any* value type?

**Example 2**

Consider another example wherein the underlying motivation is to avoid the allocation of memory for creating a new object.

In the example below, the code caches a `StringBuilder` so as to avoid creating it afresh, even though all the contents of the object are erased to make place for new contents. It's just the creation of the new object, i.e. the allocation of memory for the new object that is avoided.

From the [source of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/keyvaluepair.cs,43):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = StringBuilderCache.Acquire(0x10);
    sb.Append('[');
    if (this.Key != null)
    {
        sb.Append(this.Key.ToString());
    }
    sb.Append(", ");
    if (this.Value != null)
    {
        sb.Append(this.Value.ToString());
    }
    sb.Append(']');
    return StringBuilderCache.GetStringAndRelease(sb);
}
```

Note the first line of the code calls `StringBuilderCache.Acquire`. Below is [the code for the `StringBuilderCache` class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuildercache.cs,a6dbe82674916ac0), whose purpose is to cache an instance of a `StringBuilder` object so as to avoid re-creating it.

```
internal static class StringBuilderCache
{
    // Fields
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static StringBuilder CachedInstance;
    private const int MAX_BUILDER_SIZE = 360;

    // Methods
    public static StringBuilder Acquire(int capacity = 0x10);
    public static string GetStringAndRelease(StringBuilder sb);
    public static void Release(StringBuilder sb);
}
```

And below is the [source of the `Acquire` method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuildercache.cs,50) on this class. Note that it simply returns a cached instance of `StringBuilder`, if an instance was previously available, after emptying its contents.

```
public static StringBuilder Acquire(int capacity = 0x10)
{
    if (capacity <= 360)
    {
        StringBuilder cachedInstance = CachedInstance;
        if ((cachedInstance != null) && (capacity <= cachedInstance.Capacity))
        {
            CachedInstance = null;
            cachedInstance.Clear();
            return cachedInstance;
        }
    }
    return new StringBuilder(capacity);
}
```

**Example 3**

I just found an authoritative source alluding to the above said.

The [Using Structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-structs) page from the C# Programming Guide on the MSDN, almost at the very beginning of the article, states as follows:

> Although it is just as convenient to represent a point as a `class` with
>   Auto-Implemented Properties, a `struct` might be more efficient in some
>   scenarios. For example, if you declare an array of 1000 Point objects,
>   you will allocate additional memory for referencing each object; in
>   this case, a `struct` would be less expensive.

So, what's this hush-hush much ado about creating new objects?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203695/does-using-new-on-a-struct-allocate-it-on-the-heap-or-stack and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap.

Comment: Hmm, allocating objects is not expensive.  A C# program will handily beat a C++ program when allocation is the bottleneck.  It is *accessing* them that is more expensive.  Value types are highly compatible with the way the processor likes to use memory, being able to store values in a processor register makes a very big difference on perf.  And using the stack for storage is helpful because it is always hot.  Objects of a reference type require an extra indirection through a pointer and the processor might be bogged down when the object needs to be dug out of the slow RAM.

Comment: @HansPassant What you're saying makes a lot of sense considering this answer. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45276657/303685) This guy did a performance test of merely accessing `struct` and `class` instances, ruling out the cost of their creation, and noted a difference in access times, too.

Comment: "Surely, structs also must have a method table and a header" - why do you think so? Bear in mind that with structs there's no possibility of inheritance. When working with an unboxed struct, the methods to call are known *at compile time*.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my reading of the answers linked in Polyfun's comment to the question, I infer that the cost difference incurred in the allocation of new objects as against allocating memory for value-types is due to the difference in the number of CPU instructions.

While traversing a stack or allocating new memory on the stack is a matter of dereferencing the stack pointer by those many number of bytes, each allocation on the heap might involve traversing large portions of the heap because heaps are usually fragmented.

I have to admit this isn't new knowledge to me and I seem to have forgotten this bit while posting this question.

Yet, I want to wait for someone to provide a more rounded-up, educated answer to this question.

Comment: This is false.  Allocating an object on the heap is as simple as incrementing the heap pointer by the size of the object.  No more.  It doesn't search for fragments in the heap to fill.  If there is no space for the new object at the end of the heap, a GC will take place, compacting the heap, and then allocating the object by incrementing the heap pointer, as before.

Comment: @Servy Damn! You're right. I had forgotten that, too.

Comment: I think a key thing here that you're not thinking about is that value types *aren't* allocated memory (outside of boxing). Value types go into regions that *are already allocated for instances like them* - whether that be variables that happen to live on the stack, members of other types, etc. They *never* have their own allocation phase.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's probably the thing I don't know and am alluding to in the question. What's the *allocation phase* and why is it expensive? That's probably the core of my question. Could you please write an answer to elaborate it and link to more material about it?